# How to get the best support for Handlebars templates in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

Ideas needed: what's the best mime-type to set to `*.hbs` in Netbeans in order to get the best highlighting for Handlebars templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Handlebars, but quick look at their page suggests it uses HTML + {{expressions}}. In NetBeans 7.4, {{expressions}} in HTML are interpreted as AngularJS expression so the content is considered to be JS code.

It won't help you but editor uses different color for curly braces and their content in this case. Unless {{expression}} in Handlebar template contains something that is "wrong in JavaScript syntax perspective", you can get at least some coloring and no false errors complaining about JS syntax (that your handlebars would pretend to be)

Of course this is hacky workaround, but at least you could see {{expressions}} in your file  more easily and even (at least partially) modify their coloring.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out exactly this way in the end as well and it delivers nicely.